# Why am I getting "Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function" on Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan, function-override

I'm trying to call a function via the Etherscan UI. I made sure the input data is correct, but I keep getting this error:

```
Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The function you are calling receive not correct number of arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function overloading. As of Oct 1 at least, Etherscan seems to be having issues with contracts that have more than one function named the same.

See it for yourself:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.11;

contract A {

    uint256 public a;

    function initialize() public {
        a = 10;
    }
}

contract B is A {
    uint256 public b;

    function initialize(uint256 _b) public {
        b = _b;
    }
}
```

Deploy it with [Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org), verify the source code and then try to call the `initialize(uint256)` function. It will fail with the same error as in the question body.

I contacted their support.

#### Update

I tried to do it programatically via [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/), but I received a similar error precisely when I sent the transaction. Prior to that, there were only a few  warnings related to the function overloading.

I finally sorted it out via [MyEtherWallet](https://myetherwallet.com).